# Oculus Quest crashing when camera rotates

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

I am facing an issue with Oculus Quest crashing when i rotate my head to one side (Left) but does not crash when i look Right side. I am using LWRP and facing this issue. I have even deactivated all gameobjects on the Left side but still it does not make any difference. Any one facing this problem? Any suggestions? No error messages either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a bug with Unity with 2018 version that I was using. It used to crash even if I play particles. Upgrading the project to the latest 2019 Unity version solved the issue.